# Jquery Mobile & iOS keypad issue

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

So we're building an app using Phonegap & Jquery Mobile and we're having an issue on one of the JQM pages. The issue comes in when you're using the ios keypad's "next" button to navigate between the fields. When you come to the last input text field and you press the "Done" button, some of the page elements appear behind the "header" bar as opposed to having all the page elements in view once the "Done" button has been pressed.

On the Android version, the page's full elements are in view but the Footer bar is now gone and only when I tap the body the footer appears.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted out the issue after a full day of scratching around. A minor change was made to the jquery.mobile.css global configuration file which created the issue. The minor change was made to the following setting...

.ui-mobile [data-role=page], .ui-mobile [data-role=dialog], .ui-page { top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; min-height: 100%; position: absolute; display: none; border: 0; }

The actual change made was "! important" was inserted next to the min-height: 100% which resulted in the issue. I simply removed the "! important" and it worked.